# Apache: Can I revoke certain client certificate on certain subdomain only

Tags: openssl, apache, certificate-revocation, client, centos

I would like to know if we can make the client certificate valid for certain sub domain (Virtual Host). For example if I have two client certificate A, B.

A is valid for subdomainX but not for subdomainY.
B is valid for subdomainY but not for subdomainX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A certificate is like a passport: it is either valid or not, i.e. you cannot selectively revoke it only in specific areas. But you can specify which certificates/passports are accepted as authentication in which areas. This can be done for example by not accepting any certificates issued by a specific CA (`SSLCACertificateFile`) but additionally restricting the subject using `SSLRequire`. For more information about this see the [Apache SSL documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol), specifically the question: *"How can I allow only clients who have certificates to access a particular URL, but allow all clients to access the rest of the server?"* which shows how to apply such certificate restrictions to specific Locations only.